# FileNotFoundError while executing UNIX Commands in Jupyter notebook

Tags: unix, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Jupyter notebook and Ipython. I'm trying to run simple UNIX commands on a Jupyter Notebook, but it's not working. Could you help me out? Thank you very much. [Outcome of !echo $PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7kH3.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what's the output for !echo $PATH

Comment: Hello Ricketyship! Thank you for your interest. I have replaced the original image with an image of output of !echo $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it's visible you're using MS Windows, hence UNIX commands won't work. So instead of `echo $PATH` you can do `echo %path%` to get the desired output.